# Why is there a "Conversion Errors" tables in an MDB?

Tags: ms-access

Why would there be a "Conversion Errors" table in an MDB?

Does this mean there was an attempt to convert the MDB to a different (newer) version of Access?

Comment: Could you update your question to make it clear what additional detail you are after? Additionally if you tag ms-access you'll likely attract more expert answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my crystal ball tells me that you have opened the file with a newer access version, possibly 2007 or 2010 and you have conversion error on the table saying that some kind of driver is missing... something like

> Missing VBE reference to file MSJETSQL.TLB.

but my powers cannot go no further.

Be more specific on which errors you have in the table.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. [About the Conversion Errors table](http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/access/HP030843301033.aspx)

Comment: I'm after some more detail about this table.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that the only place a Conversion Errors table could reside would be in the *converted* file, not in the original. But I could be wrong on that. I've never seen one myself.